Run stopped scope
Is it possible to run once stopped instance of EffectScope class? Can I run and stop a scope multiple times?
<script setup>
import { ref, effectScope, watch } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
const test = ref(msg.value.length)
const scope = effectScope(false)
watch(msg, value => {
  if(value.length > 1) {
    scope.run(() => {
      test.value = msg.value.length
    })
  } else {
    scope.stop()
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ test }}</h2>
  <input v-model="msg" />
</template>

Vue SFC playground where a scope doesn't run after it was stopped.
Thank you!
